# Regex: Replace dot followed by words, with space

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need some help. I have this scenario:

```
The Mix Publishing.House exists to bring value.to your life. Next thing.
```

The desire output should be:

```
The Mix Publishing House exists to bring value to your life. Next thing.
```

I made a regex, but is not too good:

Search: `\.(\w+)`

Replace by: `.\1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach here uses lookarounds, which check that the dot is surrounded on both sides by characters:

```
Find: (?<=\w)\.(?=\w)
Replace: [ ]      <-- a single space
```

Here is a Java and Regex101 demo, showing that it is working:

### Java demo




### Regex101 demo

Answer (score 2):

You may use

**Find What**: `\b\.\b`

Replace with a space.

The `\b` matches a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) position, here, the `\.` will only match the dot that is enclosed with word chars (letters, digits or `_`).

[image]